# gRpc bidirectional stream

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Let's say I have 2 functions add and subtract on the server. Can I use bidirectional stream in this scenario to increase throughput? If so, do I have to have an identifier for each request and response to distinguish between the responses(like reqId) at the client? Normally, they will be unary calls but want to increase throughput by streaming.

Comment: Did you benchmark the throughput of an unary RPC? AFAIK, gRPC will reuse an open channel to the RPC service, so the throughput increase might not be that significant. And it also takes away your ability to massively increase throughput through running server replicas.

Comment: @Michał - Could you please elaborate on "takes away your ability to massively increase throughput through running server replicas"? When there is an open connection to a host, how could running multiple servers help increasing the throughput? Thanks.

Comment: When you execute a streaming RPC it has to be performed on a single server machine. You could deploy multiple server machines and put them behind a reverse proxy - in such case, each request could be handled by a different machine. 
  If the client was to send multiple unary requests that allows you to process multiple requests at the same time. If the client was to send a streaming request, that one request needs to be executed on a single machine.

Comment: @Michał - My understanding was that with gRPC (which uses Http/2 internally), when the connection is opened it is always between 2 machines and it stays open for the subsequent requests. That's the main difference between http/1 and http/2. So, is it correct about what you said about multiple unary requests being handled by different machines as it involves opening so many connections with different machines? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that streaming messages have lower overhead than unary RPCs. Although the gRPC team tends to discourage using streams just for this performance gain unless it is actually necessary, as the messages can't be distributed onto multiple backends, multiple threads on one backend, and it is more complicated and harder to debug. Although if you are considering doing batching with unary RPCs, then streaming do have advantages you may prefer.

If the server computes responses in the order the requests were received, then you don't need a reqId; the 1st response would be for the 1st request, 2nd for 2nd, 3rd for 3rd, etc. gRPC streams preserve message order.

Comment: Thank you. In our case server doesn't compute the responses in order. So, we will have to use reqId. Could you share more information(any articles) when you said "the messages can't be distributed onto multiple backends, multiple threads on one backend"?

Answer (score 0):

Using a bidirectional stream for higher throughput would be a bad idea.

For lower concurrent requests, both have comparable latencies. ***However, for higher loads, unary calls are much more performant.***

Streams ensure that messages are delivered in the order that they were sent, this would mean that if there are concurrent messages, there will be some kind of bottleneck.

There is no apparent reason we should prefer streams over unary, given using streams comes with additional problems like :

- Poor latency when we have concurrent price requests
- Complex implementation at the application level
- Lack of load balancing: the client will connect with one server and ignore any new servers

A detailed analysis with some benchmarks here : https://nshnt.medium.com/using-grpc-streams-for-unary-calls-cd64a1638c8a

Comment: This particular article that compares (in a rather simplistic and synthic way, I suspect) seems to indicate otherwise: https://www.vinsguru.com/grpc-vs-rest-performance-comparison/